# Find $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which satisfies $f\left(xf(y)-y^2\right)=(y+1)f(x-y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

> Find $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which satisfies $f\left(xf(y)-y^2\right)=(y+1)f(x-y)$.

My attempt:
\begin{align}
&P(x, -1): f\bigl(xf(-1)-1\bigr)=0. \\
&\text{If } f(-1) \ne 0 \implies x \leftarrow \frac {x}{f(-1)}: f(x-1)=0 \Rightarrow f \equiv 0, \text{ which is contradiction.} \\
& \implies f(-1)=0. \\
\\
&P(0, y): f\left(-y^2\right) = (y+1)f(-y). \\
\ \\
&P(x, 0): f\bigl(xf(0)\bigr)=f(x). \\
&\text{If } f(0)=1 \implies P\left(\frac {y^2}{f(y)}, y\right): 1=f(0)=(y+1)f\left(\frac{y\bigl(y-f(y)\bigr)}{f(y)}\right) \\
&f\left(\frac{y\bigl(y-f(y)\bigr)}{f(y)}\right)=\frac {1}{y+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: if you suppose that there is some $\xi \ne -1$ such that $f(\xi) = 0$, you conclude that $f(x-\xi) = \frac{f(-\xi^2)}{\xi +1}$. This way $f$ would need to be constant, and in particular $f\equiv 0$. So, we know that the only zero of $f$ is $-1$, unless $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: If you can show that $x=-1$ is the only solution to $f(x)=0$ (excluding the trivial case $f\equiv 0$) then taking $y=x+1$ gives $f(xf(x+1)-(x+1)^2)=0$ requiring $xf(x+1)-(x+1)^2=-1$ which you can easily solve for $f(x+1).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $y\ne -1$, choose $x$ such that $x f(y) -y^2=-1$. This is possible because, when $f$ is not constant, its only zero is $-1$. Then,
$$
(y+1) f\left(\frac{y^2-1}{f(y)}-y\right) = 0\Leftrightarrow \frac{y^2-1}{f(y)}-y = -1,
$$

This means that any non-constant solution satisfies $f(y)=y+1$ for any $y\ne -1$. Finally, since this candidate solution also satisfies $f(-1)=0$, it is in fact the only non-constant solution to this equation.

To conclude, this equation has two solutions: $f(x) \equiv 0$ and $f(x) = x+1$.

Comment: The conclusion $f(y) = y+1$ is not valid if $y = 1$, so one would have to obtain separately that $f(1) = 2$.